# Chroot Multiple Areas

Tags: chroot, schroot

I have chroot set up for "user" with a work area. I am looking to setup another work area on the same machine, and it is fine if you need to exit user, and login as user2 or something. Is this possible to accomplish and if so, how?

Comment: This question is not about programming; you may find better answers at [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks Chris, in the future I will direct these type of questions there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this answer. All that is needed is to add another entry into /etc/schroot/schroot.conf. Once a linux skeleton is built in there, using debootstrap, then you can chroot into the area without issues!